# Shortcut to print only 1 item from list of dictionaries

Tags: python

```
l = [
    {'bob':'hello','jim':'thanks'},
    {'bob':'world','jim':'for'},
    {'bob':'hey','jim':'the'},
    {'bob':'mundo','jim':'help'}
]

for dict in l:
    print dict['jim']
```

Is there a one liner or pythonic way of doing this?
I'm trying to retrieve a list of just 1 item in a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[d['jim'] for d in l]
```

And don't use `dict` as a variable name. It masks the `dict()` built-in.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with good ol' functional programming:

```
map(lambda d: d['jim'], l)
```

Comment: "lambda d: d['jim']"; thats what operator.itemgetter is for.

Comment: @utdemir, the time it takes to `import operator` is greater than the difference between the `lambda` and `itemgetter` versions of this statement. I tested it.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, for example:

```
In []: l
Out[]: 
[{'bob': 'hello', 'jim': 'thanks'},
 {'bob': 'world', 'jim': 'for'},
 {'bob': 'hey', 'jim': 'the'},
 {'bob': 'mundo', 'jim': 'help'},
 {'bob': 'gratzie', 'jimmy': 'a lot'}]
In []: [d['jim'] for d in l if 'jim' in d]
Out[]: ['thanks', 'for', 'the', 'help']
```